# How fast does $\frac{x}{\ln{x}}$ go to zero?

Tags: calculus

The question is how fast $\frac{x}{\ln x}$ goes to zero as $x \to 0$? I just learned a method to measure how fast a function $f(x)$ goes to zero is to compute limit $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{{f(x)}}{{{x^n}}}$ for some $n$, if this limit goes to zero, we say $f(x)$ goes to zero faster than $x^n$ and denote it as $O(x^n)$. However, based on this criterion, it look like it is OK to say $\frac{x}{\ln x}$ to be $O(x^n)$ for any $n>0$, which is very confusing.

Comment: Simply put, logarithms have sub-polynomial growth, so to get anything interesting out of it, you'll need to compare it to something else.

Comment: It looks like you have a bad definition to work with.

Comment: This is false, you say $f(x) = o(x^n)$ in this case, $O$ means $|f(x)|\le M|x^n|$ for some constant $M$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well $$\frac{f(x)}{x^n} = \frac{\frac{x}{\ln x}}{x^n} = \frac{1}{x^{n-1} \ln x}$$ so as $x\to 0$ this goes to $-\infty$ for any $n > 1$ and only goes to $0$ for $n \leq 1$

Comment: It goes to zero for $n=0,1$ as well, just as the user claims, ${1\over\log x}\to 0$ as $x\to 0$ and if you multiply by $x$ it just goes to $0$ faster, so this doesn't add to the cases he has already solved.

Answer (score 1):

Write $x=e^u$ (clearly if $x<0$ the logarithm term makes no sense) so that $u\to{-\infty}$ then you have $f(x(u))=-u^{-1}e^{-u}$ so it's slightly faster than exponentially if you want to discuss things in terms of colloquial terms. If you want an $O$ term, the one you have--i.e. $\displaystyle{x\over\log x}$--is the best one since you already have an explicit formula.